# How can a javascript function also be an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

This is a tough one to word, but how can you have Model.method() and Model() be valid at the same time?  The particular library that makes me ask this is mongoose (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/) where Model as an object represents a mongo collection and has several methods and Model as a function is a constructor for a mongo document with some methods.  I'm trying to do something similar, but it just returns a function making `typeof Model === 'function'` and never object. It is as follows:

```
let model = (function(){
        for(var i in queries){
            if(typeof i == 'function'){
                if(i == 'insert'){
                    continue;
                }
                this[i] = function(){
                    queries[i].apply(this, arguments); // queries is a separate module I've written that has methods for querying a DB
                };
            }
        }
        return (function(){
            for(var i in arguments[0]){
                if(!(i in schema) && typeof arguments[0][i] != typeof schema[i]){
                    this[i] = arguments[0][i];
                }
                else{
                    throw new Error('Invalid argument, key: ' + i + ' value: ' + arguments[0][i]);
                }
            }
            for(var i in schema.methods){
                this[i] = schema.methods[i];
            }
        });
    })();
```

Comment: *"How can a javascript object also be a function?"* It's more the other way around, JavaScript functions are objects (always).

Comment: That said, I don't see any particular properties being put on the function that ends up assigned to `model`. The fact it's an object isn't really being used (other than that we can have a reference to it) in the quoted code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All JavaScript functions are objects. That's just how JavaScript works.

```js
function alert(message) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}

function myFunction() {
  alert("This is myFunction");
}

myFunction.property = "Hello";

myFunction.recursive = myFunction;

myFunction();
alert(myFunction.property);
alert(myFunction.name);
myFunction.recursive.recursive.recursive.recursive.recursive();
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript functions are a special kind of JavaScript objects.
That means that all the functions are objects, but objects are not necessarily functions.